# Disable spellcheck attribute with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, attributes

Instead of going into all of the views in an AngularJS application, is there an easier way to add the `spellcheck="false"` attribute dynamically to all forms in an AngularJS application?

Once added, every form in the application would be like this:

```
<form spellcheck="false">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular actually overrides the HTML `FORM` element as a directive.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/form.js

You can decorate this directive in your app configuration like so:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {

  $provide.decorator('formDirective', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {

    var formDirective = $delegate[0];
    var oldCompile = formDirective.compile;

    formDirective.compile = function (tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      // get original links
      var compile = oldCompile ? oldCompile.apply(this, arguments) : {};

      tElement.attr("spellcheck", "false");

      return compile;
    };

    return $delegate;

  }]);

}]);
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just [add it with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/css5nac6/) after the DOM loads?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // ... cool onLoad stuff

    // Set form spellcheck attributes to false
    $('form').attr('spellcheck', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setAttribute` supported by all mainstream browsers.
So the simple way is just as follows(no jQuery needed):

```
angular.element(document).ready(() => {
  // type of attribute value should be String
  document.body.setAttribute('spellcheck', 'false');
});
```

the most simple answer is to add the attribute `spellcheck="false"` directly to your `body` element(WHY NOT?).